# HttpWebRequest 500 internal error but SOAPUI Works

Tags: soap, httpwebrequest

I got an error "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error." with status code "ProtocolError"

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = null;

XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
string requestEnvelopeString = SerializerHelper.ToRequestEnvelopeString(request);

soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(requestEnvelopeString);

webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(<<endpointUrl>>);
webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
webRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;

using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
   soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
}

try
{
   using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
   {
      using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
      {
         string responseEnvelopeString = reader.ReadToEnd();
      }
   }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
   string exMessage = ex.Message;
}
```

When I send the requestEnvelopeString directly through SOAPUI, it works, could anyone suggest how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the problem is SOAP-ACTION header missing, SOAPUI will auto add to the request.

Thanks
mintssoul

Comment: In my case it was rather the domain name used